# How to select the monitor a Unity game opens on, on the first try

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to specify which monitor (1? 2? ...) my Unity game opens on, when running its .exe from the command line.

As seen on the Unity Answers post [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/844193/switch-monitor-during-runtime.html), this C# code does work:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("UnitySelectMonitor", 1); // Select monitor 2
```

However, the setting does not take effect until you close the game and re-open it. (This flaw is acknowledged in that post as well.)

Is there a way to open the game on the desired monitor on the first try?

---

(Note: I assume the solution needs to be in the build step or a command-line arg to the .exe that starts the Unity Player. Because if the solution is in the C# code itself, as the above solution is, then the game will already be open and then it's too late.)

Comment: Thanks for the link! But not quite. The earliest Direct3D shown as an option for me is 11, whereas that link suggests using no later than 9 since there's a bug after that.

Comment: I actually take that back, it appears to be working for me!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since version 2019.3, use the `-monitor` [command line argument](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html). E.g.,:

```
 GameExecutable.exe -screen-fullscreen 1 -monitor 2
```

In Unity of versions > 2019.3.0b12, 2020.1.0a12, a related bug about running multiple instances of the same application simultaneously was fixed. From the [bug tracker](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/command-line-argument-adapter-not-working-when-running-two-instances-at-the-same-time):

> IMPORTANT: the "adapter" command-line argument has been replaced with
>   "monitor" in 2019.3 (for consistency across Desktop platforms); the
>   behavior is exactly the same.
>
> NOTE: This issue also occurs for other "screen" command-line
>   parameters: screen-width, screen-height, and screen-fullscreen which
>   are also addressed by the fix.
>
> The problem is caused because these command-line arguments will
>   set/update PlayerPrefs, i.e. these values are persisted and applied
>   the next time the app is launched. So, the second instance of the app
>   essentially "inherits" the values from the first process, causing it
>   to ignore it's own command-line arguments due to a race-condition with
>   PlayerPrefs updating logic. However, if the second process is delayed
>   by a few seconds, the race-condition doesn't occur and the command
>   arguments work properly.
>
> The fix address the race-condition by setting "override" values when
>   these arguments are passed in, forcing the runtime to apply the
>   command-line values and ignore those stored in PlayerPrefs.
>
> However, PlayerPrefs is updated by the command arguments, which is
>   still a race-condition, and there's no guarantee as to which values
>   will actually be saved. That is, the values from the first instance of
>   the app may get saved to PlayerPrefs and not the values from the
>   second instance as you might expect. Unity cannot solve this problem
>   as the race occurs externally to the runtime, and so if the final
>   state of PlayerPrefs is important, then you must stagger launching
>   each instance of the app.